# Which licence choose for a new academic computing language?

Tags: open-science, license

> Disclaimer: I am not sure this is the right place to ask the question, but since it is directly related to academic work, I though I'll give it a try. If it is not, please feel free to redirect

Together with colleagues from different institutions (all academic), we have been developing a new information language (more precisely a format), based on XML, to store a specific type of information. This format is primarily directed to the academic world and will be open source

My question is: do we need to **attach a licence** to this new format and, if yes, what **type of licence** is suitable for that?

Comment: Seeing as the question is not about academia, but rather something that has the slightest connection to academia, I think it might be a better fit for Programmers.SE

Comment: I know it's maybe a bit late to do this and I know this is not the question (and I apologize for the offtopic) but I've to get this out of my chest. [Have you considered RDF?](http://j.mp/open__data)

Answer (score 5):

Oh, no, [yet another format!](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Now seriously, you can legally [register a format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_format), but I don't see a big benefit from doing it.  For what [I see,](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html) licensing is essentially a copyright of the actual text. In most practical purposes, having a public, freely available document explaining it, should suffice.

To support my feeling, I have been digging in [some](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15317041) academic [examples](http://www.psidev.info/mzidentml#mzIdentML1_1_0) I am familiar with and they don't specify any.

If you want to be sure, you could see what other people have done, for example, [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) format.